# How to convert array in PHP [nesting]

Tags: php, arrays

please, I need help.
How to convert my array via PHP

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => Orange
    [2] => Tomato
)
```

To this

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Orange] => Array
                (
                    [Tomato] => Array()
                )

        )

)
```

And i do not know how many elements in my array.
Thank all.

Comment: Interesting Question ...

Comment: Thank all. All answers is superior.

Comment: and what homework did SO help to complete? ;-). Still, interesting question with interesting answers

Comment: Сypherabe, my question - just a question. I am very pleased, that a lot of people responded to the challenge with their interesting and so different solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => Orange
    [2] => Tomato
    [3] => Banana
    [4] => Papaya
)
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Orange] => Array
                (
                    [Tomato] => Array
                        (
                            [Banana] => Array
                                (
                                    [Papaya] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Code**

```
$fruits = [

  "Apple",
  "Orange",
  "Tomato",
  "Banana",
  "Papaya"

];

// Result Array

$result = [

  $fruits[count($fruits) - 1] => []

];

// Process

for ($counter = count($fruits) - 2; $counter >= 0; $counter--) {

  $temp = $result;

  unset($result);

  $result[$fruits[$counter]] = $temp;

}

// Display

echo "<pre>".print_r($fruits, true)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 5):

Try This:

```
$array = array('apple','orange','tomato');
$count = count($array) - 1;
$tempArray = array();
for($i = $count; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
    $tempArray = array($array[$i] => $tempArray);
}
```

Comment: `And i do not know how many elements in my array. ` Read question carefully.

Comment: @u_mulder: thanks yes you are right, answer updated. please check

Comment: @DishaV.: yes solution is simple and short

Answer (score 5):

try it with:

```
$target = array();
$value = array();
$path = array('apple', 'orange', 'tomato');

$rv = &$target;
foreach($path as $pk)
{
    $rv = &$rv[$pk];
}
$rv = $value;
unset($rv);

print_r($target);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [apple] => Array
        (
            [orange] => Array
                (
                    [tomato] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Update 1: Explaination**

Here I am using reference/variable alias to traverse the dynamic stack of keys. The reference makes it possible to use a stack instead of recursion which is generally more lean. Additionally this code prevents to overwrite existing elements in the `$target` array.
For more detail on references have a look at [Reference Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

```
$target = array(); //target array where we will store required out put
$value = array(); //last value i.e. blank array
$path = array('apple', 'orange', 'tomato'); //current array

$rv = &$target; //assign address of $target to $rv (reference variable)

foreach($path as $pk)
{
    $rv = &$rv[$pk]; // Unused reference [ex. $rv['apple'] then $rv['apple']['orange'] .. so on ] - actually assigned to $target by reference

    print_r($target);
    echo '-----------------<br />';
}
$rv = $value; //here $rv have unused refernce of value tomato so finally assigned a blank array to key tomoto
//
unset($rv); // Array copy is now unaffected by above reference

echo "final array<br />";
print_r($target);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [apple] => 
)
-----------------
Array
(
    [apple] => Array
        (
            [orange] => 
        )

)
-----------------
Array
(
    [apple] => Array
        (
            [orange] => Array
                (
                    [tomato] => 
                )

        )

)
-----------------
final array
Array
(
    [apple] => Array
        (
            [orange] => Array
                (
                    [tomato] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

In output of explaination you can trace the value of `$target` in `foreach` loop

Comment: Can you please explain the solution.

Comment: @VedPandya sure let me update my answer. I will add comment in code so every one can understand the flow of code

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way also with `foreach` and `ksort`:

```
<?php

$fruits = array(

  "Apple",
  "Orange",
  "Tomato",
  "Banana",
  "Papaya"

);
krsort($fruits);
$tmp = array();
foreach($fruits as $fruit){
        $tmp =  array($fruit => $tmp);
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($tmp, true)."</pre>";

?>
```

[Proof of concept]

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Orange] => Array
                (
                    [Tomato] => Array
                        (
                            [Banana] => Array
                                (
                                    [Papaya] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank, this solution great.

Answer (score 2):

While loop and [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php):

```
$fruits = [
    "Apple",
    "Orange",
    "Tomato",
    "Banana",
    "Papaya"
];

$output = [];
while ( $fruit = array_pop($fruits) )
{
    $output = [$fruit => $output];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_reduce(array_reverse($fruits), function (array $acc, $fruit) {
    return [$fruit => $acc];
}, []);
```

You simply start from the inside out and wrap the value into a `$key => $value` array.